# how to format Angular number pipe output

Tags: angular

I am using angular number pipe to round off to 2 digits as 
[input |number: '1.2-2'], but angular number pipe gives result in comma format. 
Input: 1439.333, 
output: 1,439.33, 
expectedoutput: 1439.33. 
Is there any way to do this. I am on angular 2, and dont want to use javascript.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Viewed here : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DecimalPipe-pipe.html

> WARNING: this pipe uses the Internationalization API which is not yet available in all browsers and may require a polyfill. See Browser support for details.

Edit : 
you also could force the locale used by the Angular's pipe by adding something like this in your app.module.ts :

```
providers: [
  { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "en-US" }, //try some locale here
  appRoutingProviders,
  ...
]`
```

Comment: I have used this one only, its giving comma in output.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own Pipe :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'numberFormat'})
export class NumberFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
 transform(value: number): number {
    return ...;
  }
}
```

Comment: wondering whether it can be done without custom pipes, i wanted to handle it on html side only where i am using it, using other pipes or something.

Comment: But the Angular's pipe is based on `Intl.NumberFormat` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a custom pipe and add it to you html after using number pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'commadumper'})

export class NumberFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: number): number {
        if (!value) {
           return '';
        }
        return value.replace(',', '');
    }
}
```

Then in your html you can use it like this:

```
[input |number: '1.2-2' | commadumper]
```

**BTW**: before doing anything I suggest checking your system number formatting (I mean client side), since it might be that adding the comma.