# Change number formatting in Angular pipe to group numbers with space

Tags: html, angular, typescript, format, pipe

I want to change format of number from: 225363.5 to 22 536,50.

I already tried this:
`{{value | number : '1.2-2' }}` and `{{ value | currency}}` and the result was $22,536.50 and 22,536.50.

I don't want to display the comma ","

Comment: I'd use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40862629/215552), but replace the comma with a space rather than the empty string.

Comment: You can write your [own pipe](https://angular.io/api/core/Pipe). Just add a space after second number and replace('.', ',')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify locale thousand separator for number pipe in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44672225/how-to-specify-locale-thousand-separator-for-number-pipe-in-angular-4)